# django migration error 137

Tags: django, migration

Migrating on my production server I get the following error:
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states...make: *** [migrate] Error 137

I didn't have a problem migrating in my development environment.

My migration doesn't seem complicated.  Any suggestions on where to look for the problem?

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

```
dependencies = [
    ('cohort', '0075_auto_20160504_1543'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='cohort',
        name='agreement_template',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='cohort',
        name='flat_fee',
        field=models.DecimalField(default=1000, verbose_name='Flat Polestar Fee', max_digits=8, decimal_places=2),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='cohort',
        name='travel_expense',
        field=models.DecimalField(default=0, verbose_name='Expected Travel Expense per Module', max_digits=7, decimal_places=2),
    ),
]
```

Comment: I got past it by stopping the webserver and running the migration with the server stopped.  That doesn't seem to be the best approach to doing things though.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: A bit more info needed (an extract from the stack trace and what your database is)

Comment: Thanks.  Yes - I was going to run the migration --verbose.  But as I succeeded in getting the migration to work when I stopped the services prior to migration, I am unable to replicate the error.

Comment: My database is psql  
It even occurs if there is no migration to apply.
There is no stack trace - I just get:

Comment: Running migrations:
  Rendering model states...make: *** [migrate] Error 137  (I'm running in a makefile)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that my database server (AWS) was t1.micro.  It seems it was running out of memory during rendering.  I upgraded it to m1.small and that solved the problem.